# How can I determine from Javascript/jquery if a specfic Google Chrome extension is installed?

Tags: google-chrome, clickonce

My application requires Chrome users to have a specific extension installed

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clickonce-for-google-chro/eeifaoomkminpbeebjdmdojbhmagnncl
```

Using JQuery/JavaScript, how can I determine if this extension is installed?  I've seen some mentions of using **chrome.management.get** but I haven't found any working examples.

The reason I need the extension is ClickOnce applications won't launch in chrome unless this is installed.

Comment: Good question.  I have multiple ClickOnce applications and it's been along time since I tried to find a reliable way to install my applications through Chrome or Firefox.  In my case, I never found an acceptable way to assure that a user could install my application through either browser.  As such, I just tested for the browser and if the user wasn't using IE, I informed them to install the application through Internet Explorer.  It's not elegant but it works.

Comment: Sorry, one more note.  Yes, I am aware of extensions like the one you've linked, and there has been a plugin for Firefox for years.  However, what I couldn't find was an easy and reliable way to test and force my users to install these plugins and extensions.  As such, I simplified the process and just told my users to go to IE.  I've never had a single complaint about this requirement, even though 25% of my users use something other than IE.